# Find by the method of characteristic, the integral surface which passes through the curve

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find by the method of characteristic, the integral surface of $$pq=xy$$ which passes through the curve $$z=x,y=0$$

By strip condition, there is a unique initial strip $$x_{0}=s,y_{0}=0,z_{0}=s,p_{0}=1,q_{0}=0$$

And the characteristic equations are

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=f_p,\\ \frac{dy}{dt}=f_q, 
\\ \frac{dz}{dt}=pf_p+qf_q,
\\ \frac{dp}{dt}=-f_x-pf_z,
\\ \frac{dq}{dt}=-f_y-qf_z$$
where $f$ is given non linear pde. 
Please help me to eliminate s and t find z in x & y.

Comment: My apologies, but are P and Q vector fields?  It seems like x,y, and z share parameter t, but do they also share parameter s?  I can't quite tell what each unknown is supposed to represent.  A little more clarity would be helpful, if you please.

Comment: Sorry it's small p and q. I corrected

Comment: Okay, thank you, that does help a lot.  A few more questions:  are p and q functions of t and s, too?  Or at they just variables?  If so, are they members of the set of complex numbers?  If you can narrow down exactly what each variable/function is, it will make solving this problem easier for both of us.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=xy\quad;\quad z(x,0)=x$$

Preliminary comment :

The solution is very easy by separation of variables. We look for particular solution on the form $z(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$
$$(g\frac{df}{dx})(f\frac{dg}{dy})=xy\quad\implies\quad 
\begin{cases}
fdf=xdx \quad f=\pm\sqrt{x^2+c_1}\\
gdg=ydy\quad g=\pm\sqrt{y^2+c_2}
\end{cases}$$

$$z=\pm\sqrt{(x^2+c_1)(y^2+c_2)}$$
With condition $z(x,0)=x=\pm\sqrt{(x^2+c_1)c_2} \implies c_1=0$ ; $c_2=1$ ; sign of $x$.
$$\boxed{z(x,y)=x\sqrt{y^2+1}}$$

Solving with method of characteristics :
$$\frac{dx}{q}=\frac{dy}{p}=\frac{dz}{2pq}=\frac{dp}{y}=\frac{dq}{x}=dt $$
$$x_{0}=s,y_{0}=0,z_{0}=s,p_{0}=1,q_{0}=0$$
Solving the system leads to :
$$\begin{cases}
x=Ae^{t}+Be^{-t} \\
y=Ce^{t}+De^{-t} \\
p=Ce^{2t}-De^{2t}\\
q=Ae^{2t}-Be^{2t}\\
z=ACe^{2t}-BDe^{2t}+E 
\end{cases}$$
$pq-xy=0 \implies AB+BC=0$

With boundary condition : $p_0=1$ and $q_0=0$

$A+B=s\quad;\quad C+D=0\quad;\quad AC-BD+E=s\quad;\quad C-D=1\quad;\quad A-B=0\quad;\quad AD+BC=0$.

$A=B=E=\frac{s}{2}$ and $C=-D=\frac12$ $\quad\implies\quad$ 
$\begin{cases}
x=s \cosh(t) \\
y= \sinh(t) \\
z=\frac{s}{2}(\cosh(2t)+1)=s \cosh^2(t)
\end{cases}$

$x^2-s^2y^2=s^2\quad\implies\quad s^2=\frac{x^2}{y^2+1}$

$z=\frac{x^2}{s}=x^2\left(\frac{+\sqrt{y^2+1}}{x}\right)$ . The sign $+$ is determined according to $z(x,0)=x$ .
$$z=x\sqrt{y^2+1}$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to solve that system of ODEs in method of characteristics. It would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $\begin{cases}p=x^2\\q=y^2\end{cases}$ ,

Then $z_x=z_pp_x+z_qq_x=2xz_p$

$z_y=z_pp_y+z_qq_y=2yz_q$

$\therefore2xz_p2yz_q=xy$ with $z(\sqrt p,0)=\sqrt p$

$z_p=\dfrac{1}{4z_q}$ with $z(p,0)=p$